# The integral of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How can I integrate this by parts? It seems to become recursive. I'm familiar with the *classical* solution, and cannot use that here due to the constraints of this class.

Here's the integral (to infinity). https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKnDo.png

$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-x^2}} dx$$

I'm having trouble finding the indefinite integral first.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no closed form for the indefinite integral. Are you allowed to use gamma function?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not :/

Here's what a friend sent me. It looks like he may be wrong, and I'm not certain of what he's doing either.  

http://i.imgur.com/mgvR0Pv.jpg

Comment: Looks like he has a sign error somewhere.

Comment: Your friend apparently integrated by parts once and then back. The terms didn't cancel so I suppose it's a sign error.

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ function is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). It is not an elementary function, and because of [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) we are not able to express the error function in term of elementary functions. Liouville's theorem charaterise the class of functions for which we could find an elementary primitive function. [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) is a tool inspired be Liouville's theorem.

What you are looking for is the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). You could find more then one proof at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), or at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_of_Exponent_of_Half_Square_over_Reals).

Answer (score 0):

There is is no elementary function for the indefinite gaussian integral. The best you can do is represent it through a Taylor series, and then compute it numerically with the desired precision.

Yet calculating the indefinite integral is straightforward ([wikipedia has several proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates)).

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\pi$$

As the integrand is an even function:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$